# Transformed children contains strange parent width

Tags: html, css, transform

I've got a simple HTML Markup:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

The child element is moved by `transform: translate(-100%);` out of the viewport but the parent width does not move with the child element:

This is my simplified CSS:

```
.parent {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    left: 0;
}

.parent .child {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    background: orange;
    transform: translate(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-100%);
    -o-transform: translate(-100%);
}
```

Have a look:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When transforming and element its parents aren't affected. This is how CSS transforms are supposed to work. From [Using CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms):

> By modifying the coordinate space, **CSS transforms change the shape and position of the affected content without disrupting the normal document flow**.

Comment: @susanloek When you don't apply the transformation, you see how the container is filled with the child elements (the "slide-out-elements") and has a final computed width and height of `n x m px`. Then you move the children to the left, using transform. As stated "*CSS transforms change the shape and position of the affected content without disrupting the normal document flow*". So the parent container keeps it's computed size, no matter how you transform it's children.